# Edge and Chrome Changing Downloaded File Extention

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, 7-zip, microsoft-edge

I'm downloading a file with the .lzp extension that both Chrome and Edge are changing it to .zip. It does appear to be a zip file just with a new extension. But the program that I'm using it for, the dialog only will take .lzp files. Manually changing the extension is fine but a minor nuisance. I've used this program for close to 20 years and never had a problem until this new Win10 laptop.